# How can i auto select children option when selected parent option Js, Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have structor like

```html
<div id="choose-categories" class="ms-drop bottom" style="display: block;">
  <ul style="max-height: 250px;">
    <li class="level-0">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="selectItemallow[]" value="1">
        Du Lịch
      </label>
    </li>
    <li class="level-0">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="selectItemallow[]" value="3">
        Ẩm Thực
      </label>
    </li>
    <li class="level-1">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="selectItemallow[]" value="86">
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Ẩm Thực Đường Phố
      </label>
    </li>
    <li class="level-1">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="selectItemallow[]" value="87">
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Món Ngon
      </label>
    </li>
    <li class="level-0">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="selectItemallow[]" value="9">
        Videos Giải Trí
      </label>
    </li>
    <li class="level-0">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="selectItemallow[]" value="81">
        Làm Đẹp</label>
    </li>
    <li class="level-1">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="selectItemallow[]" value="82">
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Nail
      </label>
    </li>
    <li class="level-1">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="selectItemallow[]" value="83">
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Trang Điểm
      </label>
    </li>
    <li class="level-1">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="selectItemallow[]" value="84">
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Làm Tóc
      </label>
    </li>
    <li class="level-1">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="selectItemallow[]" value="85">
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Tattoo
      </label>
    </li>
    <li class="ms-no-results" style="display: none;">
      No matches found
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

What i need is i want choose level-0, it's will auto choose all lv-1 after it (child selection) and stop in lv-0 next.
How can i do it with JS or Jquery

Comment: I try all night, but i cant find or do somethings with it :(

Comment: Can you be more specific on what you want to select? I don't understand if you want to select all level-0s and the first level-1s after the level-0s ?

Comment: "the first level-1s after the level-0s " yes, but it's not enough. What i want is - When I select class = "level-0", the website will automatically select all the next = "level-1" classes until it meets the next (or none) class = "level-0".

Comment: Ex: when i click "Ẩm Thực" website wil auto select "Ẩm Thực Đường Phố" and "Món Ngon" and stop. or i choose "Làm Đẹp" website will auto select all "Nail", "Trang Điểm", "Làm Tóc", "Tattoo".

Comment: I added   a bonus  in may answer about  checked/unchecked level-1 action to resume level-0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is what you want. When a level-0 checkbox changes you want each of the following level-1 to change the same as the one you changed.

You traverse to the parent `<li>` and use [nextUntil()](https://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/) to get the following group. Then change checked property of each of those checkboxes

```js
$('.level-0 :checkbox').change(function(){
   // from parent <li> get all siblings until next level-0
   const $level_1 = $(this).closest('li.level-0').nextUntil('.level-0');
   // set checked in them based on checked state of current one
   $level_1.find(':checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="choose-categories" class="ms-drop bottom" style="display: block;">
  <ul style="max-height: 250px;">
    <li class="level-0">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="selectItemallow[]" value="1">
        Du Lịch
      </label>
    </li>
    <li class="level-0">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="selectItemallow[]" value="3">
        Ẩm Thực
      </label>
    </li>
    <li class="level-1">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="selectItemallow[]" value="86">
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Ẩm Thực Đường Phố
      </label>
    </li>
    <li class="level-1">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="selectItemallow[]" value="87">
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Món Ngon
      </label>
    </li>
    <li class="level-0">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="selectItemallow[]" value="9">
        Videos Giải Trí
      </label>
    </li>
    <li class="level-0">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="selectItemallow[]" value="81">
        Làm Đẹp</label>
    </li>
    <li class="level-1">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="selectItemallow[]" value="82">
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Nail
      </label>
    </li>
    <li class="level-1">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="selectItemallow[]" value="83">
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Trang Điểm
      </label>
    </li>
    <li class="level-1">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="selectItemallow[]" value="84">
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Làm Tóc
      </label>
    </li>
    <li class="level-1">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="selectItemallow[]" value="85">
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Tattoo
      </label>
    </li>
    <li class="ms-no-results" style="display: none;">
      No matches found
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: wow, thank you so much, that's what i want. you help me get rid of many sleepless nights

Comment: Thank you so much, but if you can, please help me 1 more time. When i choose option, it will add class="selected" to that element. And i try with your code, it's not add class to children element. can you show me how to do that, please ?

Comment: `$(this).addClass(...)` for current one and you can chain `.prop('checked', this.checked).addClass(..)` for the others.

Comment: I dont know why, but i have some error with class : https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1TGi6cwLG2QsB_mfFVlL0jbi4Z0fubn0z?usp=sharing
When i select level-0, it check to level-1, but not add class 'selected' to.
And when i unselect level-1, it will add class 'selected' to @@ OMG

Comment: it will correct when i check to element, and add class 'selected' to too@@ maybe it's error of js ?

Comment: Hard to help from images without a runnable [mcve]

Comment: if you give me a little bit of time, can i send you my teamviewer ?

Comment: OMG, i try : $level_1.addClass(... and it's work. Thank you so much

Comment: Oh.. I thought it was for the inputs...my bad. Also take a look at `toggleClass('className', this.checked)`. Will add or remove depending on the checkbox being checked

Comment: nah, not you fault, you help me too much today. Thank you too much ^^

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's [nextUntil](https://api.jquery.com/nextuntil/) might be able to help a bit with this:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.level-0').change(function () {
    var status = $('input[type="checkbox"]', this).is(':checked');
    var nextChks = $(this).nextUntil('.level-0');
    if (nextChks && nextChks.length > 0) {
      for (var i = 0; i < nextChks.length; i++) {
        $('input[type="checkbox"]', nextChks[i]).attr('checked', status).prop('checked', status);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="choose-categories" class="ms-drop bottom" style="display: block;">
  <ul style="max-height: 250px;">
    <li class="level-0">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="selectItemallow[]" value="1">
        Du Lịch
      </label>
    </li>
    <li class="level-0">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="selectItemallow[]" value="3">
        Ẩm Thực
      </label>
    </li>
    <li class="level-1">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="selectItemallow[]" value="86">
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Ẩm Thực Đường Phố
      </label>
    </li>
    <li class="level-1">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="selectItemallow[]" value="87">
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Món Ngon
      </label>
    </li>
    <li class="level-0">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="selectItemallow[]" value="9">
        Videos Giải Trí
      </label>
    </li>
    <li class="level-0">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="selectItemallow[]" value="81">
        Làm Đẹp</label>
    </li>
    <li class="level-1">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="selectItemallow[]" value="82">
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Nail
      </label>
    </li>
    <li class="level-1">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="selectItemallow[]" value="83">
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Trang Điểm
      </label>
    </li>
    <li class="level-1">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="selectItemallow[]" value="84">
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Làm Tóc
      </label>
    </li>
    <li class="level-1">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="selectItemallow[]" value="85">
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Tattoo
      </label>
    </li>
    <li class="ms-no-results" style="display: none;">
      No matches found
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do that

> with a bonus on checked/unchecked level-1 action to resume level-0

```js
const 
  allCats = document.querySelector('#choose-categories')
, LevCats = [...allCats.querySelectorAll('li')]  
;
allCats.onclick = ({target}) =>
  {
  if (!target.matches('input[type=checkbox]')) return
 
  let liParent = target.closest('li')
    , liRef    = LevCats.findIndex(x=>x===liParent)
    ;
  if (liParent.classList.contains('level-0'))
    {
    for (let i = ++liRef; i < LevCats.length; ++i)
    if (LevCats[i].classList.contains('level-1') )
      LevCats[i].querySelector('input[type=checkbox]').checked = target.checked
    else
      break 
    }
  else // if (liParent.classList.contains('level-1')) *** BONUS ***
    {
    while ( !LevCats[--liRef].classList.contains('level-0') ) {}
    if (target.checked)
      LevCats[liRef].querySelector('input[type=checkbox]').checked = true
    else
      {
      checkedCount = 0
      for (let i = ++liRef; i < LevCats.length; ++i)
      if (LevCats[i].classList.contains('level-1') )
        { if (LevCats[i].querySelector('input[type=checkbox]').checked ) checkedCount++ }
      else
        break;
      if (checkedCount === 0) LevCats[--liRef].querySelector('input[type=checkbox]').checked = false
      }
    }
  }
```

```css
li.level-1 span::before { content : '\2015\2015'; color:lightgrey; }
```

```html
<div id="choose-categories" class="ms-drop bottom" style="display: block;">
  <ul style="max-height: 250px;">
    <li class="level-0">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="selectItemallow[]" value="1">
        <span>Du Lịch</span>
      </label>
    </li>
    <li class="level-0">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="selectItemallow[]" value="3">
        <span>Ẩm Thực</span>
      </label>
    </li>
    <li class="level-1">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="selectItemallow[]" value="86">
        <span>Ẩm Thực Đường Phố</span>
      </label>
    </li>
    <li class="level-1">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="selectItemallow[]" value="87">
        <span>Món Ngon</span>
      </label>
    </li>
    <li class="level-0">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="selectItemallow[]" value="9">
        <span>Videos Giải Trí</span>
      </label>
    </li>
    <li class="level-0">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="selectItemallow[]" value="81">
        <span>Làm Đẹp</span>
      </label>
    </li>
    <li class="level-1">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="selectItemallow[]" value="82">
        <span>Nail</span>
      </label>
    </li>
    <li class="level-1">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="selectItemallow[]" value="83">
        <span>Trang Điểm</span>
      </label>
    </li>
    <li class="level-1">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="selectItemallow[]" value="84">
        <span>Làm Tóc</span>
      </label>
    </li>
    <li class="level-1">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="selectItemallow[]" value="85">
        <span>Tattoo</span>
      </label>
    </li>
    <li class="ms-no-results" style="display: none;">
      No matches found
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can/are allowed to change the html, you can make it to look like a tree, like the snippet below.. and what I did was

1. to add classes to each parent who has childrens and to each children itself (for the first group `first-main-checkbox` and `first-sub-checkbox` and for the second one with the second key word in class name)
2. get all elements with  `document.querySelectorAll(".first-sub-checkbox");` which return a NodeList (see [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) )
3. create a function who iterate through all elements returned by querySelectorAll and set the check `state` to `true` or `false` using a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)
4. apply the function at click, which select/deselect checkbox: `addEventListener("click", function)` (see [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener))

I'm not saying that it's the best solution, but it's a start..

```js
var firstMain = document.querySelector(".first-main-checkbox");
var firstChildrens = document.querySelectorAll(".first-sub-checkbox");

var secondMain = document.querySelector(".second-main-checkbox");
var secondChildrens = document.querySelectorAll(".second-sub-checkbox");



function toggleCheck(childrens) {
  childrens.forEach(child => {
    child.checked = child.checked == true ? false : true
  })
}

firstMain.addEventListener("click", function() {
  toggleCheck(firstChildrens)
});
secondMain.addEventListener("click", function() {
  toggleCheck(secondChildrens)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="choose-categories" class="ms-drop bottom" style="display: block;">
  <ul style="max-height: 250px;">
    <li class="level-0">
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="selectItemallow[]" value="1">Du Lịch</label>
    </li>

    <li class="level-0">
      <label><input class="first-main-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="selectItemallow[]" value="3">Ẩm Thực</label>
      <ul>
        <li class="level-1">
          <label><input class="first-sub-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="selectItemallow[]" value="86">Ẩm Thực Đường Phố</label>
        </li>
        <li class="level-1">
          <label><input class="first-sub-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="selectItemallow[]" value="87">Món Ngon</label>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="level-0">
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="selectItemallow[]" value="9">Videos Giải Trí</label>
    </li>
    <li class="level-0">
      <label><input class="second-main-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="selectItemallow[]" value="81">Làm Đẹp</label>
    </li>
    <ul>
      <li class="level-1">
        <label><input class="second-sub-checkbox"type="checkbox" name="selectItemallow[]" value="82"> Nail</label>
      </li>
      <li class="level-1">
        <label><input class="second-sub-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="selectItemallow[]" value="83">Trang Điểm</label>
      </li>
      <li class="level-1">
        <label><input class="second-sub-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="selectItemallow[]" value="84">Làm Tóc</label>
      </li>
      <li class="level-1">
        <label><input class="second-sub-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="selectItemallow[]" value="85">Tattoo</label>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <li class="level-0">
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="selectItemallow[]" value="1">another lv 0 item</label>
    </li>
    <li class="ms-no-results" style="display: none;">
      No matches found
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: But your code is wrong  => if a level-1 ichecked with his level-0 unchecked, then when you check the level-0, the previous level-1 is unchecked...

Comment: i think that's great, but i cant change structor like this. thankyou anyway

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure but gonna try.

You have element inside of event parameter so get `li` from it by calling `parent('li')`
then find all siblings that are after it by calling `next('li')` and do loop like this

```
const nexts = [];
par.next('li').foreach(function (elem) {
     if (elem.hasClass('level-0') && nexts.length > 0)
          return false; // break loop
     if (elem.hasClass('level-1'))
          nexts.push(elem); // add li element
});
```

then just go through nexts and for each find its input which you marked as checked. That's it.

Comment: Numerous things here that aren't right and/or will throw errors. You might want to test this yourself

Comment: Thank you very much, and very grateful for what you did. But I'm not really good at writing js or jquery. So if you can help me with more specific code to help me. please